# Hibernate a Dell laptop with a single key press

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard, hibernate, dell-xps

In my HP laptop, near the F1 button, there is a moon icon. When I click Fn+F1, the laptop immediately goes into hibernation. This is very convenient to me.

In my Dell XPS laptop (with Windows 10) there is no moon icon, so I thought there was no way to hibernate it from the keyboard. Of course I can use the Windows start menu, but it less convenient. Another option is to remap the power button to hibernate, but this has the drawback that I do not have a power button (for example, in case I need to do hard reset).

Is there any way I can put my Dell laptop to hibernation with a single key combination, without losing the functionality of other keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long search, I finally found the secret key combination that works: it is **Fn+Insert**. Although there is no moon icon near the Insert button, clicking Fn+Insert immediately puts my Dell XPS Windows laptop in hibernation. No key-remapping is required.

I write it here in order to help other Dell users who have the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this!... I was looking for this key combo as knew that I had accidentally triggered it a few months ago, but couldn't find any mention of it on either Microsoft's or Dell's website!